# How can I share a selected photo from a grid through Facebook and Twitter

Tags: blackberry

I want to share a photo through Facebook and Twitter in my Blackberry app. From the SDcard, load all the photos to a grid and select one image to share. Can anyone please share some code snippet for this?

Comment: Please begin by describing your problem thoroughly. That is often the first step to producing code of your own.

Comment: yes will help you. first tell us what you have tried ?

Comment: did you try strawberry app for blackberry ?.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick reply. First I tried too integrate facebook api into my app. I downloaded the api from http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/ and followed the instructions in the readme file. But when I try to share nothing happens. Then I tried another example I got from internet(Sorry. I don't remember whether it is strawberry app). While running that code it goes to gallery and I am able to select a picture and share. It is working perfectly. But I want the images in a grid or a horizontal scrollview and on clicking one image, user should be able to share that image.

Comment: try picturescroll demo app. also on click of that call the function of image sharing